# Many kinect devices and one PC

Tags: python, kinect, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I want to monitor 3d activity on **15x15m scene** from the top.

Since kinect hanged on 5meters sees surface of approximately **4m/5m**, I want to connect **9 kinects** to one PC and read the signal from those devices to C or preferably python program.

Apparently there are may be two possible problems:
- USB bandwidth of 9 kinects may be higher than overall USB bus speed (is there any way to disable camera and leave ony infrared on?)
- software can have some limits when it comes to initializing many kinects

**Is there any possibility to seamlessly connect multiple kinect devices to one PC** and read the signal using **openkinect** or **python** wrapper for openkinect? If not - what would be alternative solution?

Note: I'm fluent in C and python

Comment: Definitely possible with openkinect, don't know if the Python wrapper can do it too. See this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openkinect/DLTOYik0BeE

Comment: You will need to use a lot of usb buses (not ports). I've got 3 working using an expansion card to extend to another powered usb bus. Also, processing everything in real time after all this heavy duty usb  transfers might be slow. How about splitting the task to multiple computers sending only essential/processed/tracked data via udp ?